# Maven install fails on ubuntu due to broken packages

Tags: maven, ubuntu-14.04, apt-get

I am trying to install maven but getting error for broken packages. I tried with -f switch too but it did not helped.

```
simon@simon-pc:~$ sudo apt-get install -f maven
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 maven : Depends: libaether-java but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libplexus-containers1.5-java but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libsisu-ioc-java but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libwagon-java but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Why not downloading [Maven Distribution from Maven Downlaod Page](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) an unpack it and put the bin folder to path...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following commands:

```
#sudo apt-get remove maven2
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/natecarlson/maven3/ubuntu precise main"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install maven3
```

If you encounter this:

The program 'mvn' can be found in the following packages:

maven

maven2

Try sudo apt-get install {selected-package}

```
#Just add those lines in /etc/profile
export M2_HOME=/usr/share/maven3
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
export PATH=$M2:$PATH
```